# Maven Web Project + Tomcat + jRebel

Tags: maven, tomcat7, jrebel

I just bought a license and I am having problems to setup the jRebel.

My project is a Java Web Maven Project
Product Version: 
NetBeans IDE 8.1 (Build 201510222201)
Updates: NetBeans IDE is updated to version NetBeans 8.1 Patch 1
Java: 1.8.0_74; Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 25.74-b02
Runtime: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 1.8.0_74-b02
System: Mac OS X version 10.11.4 running on x86_64; UTF-8; en_US (nb)
Frameworks: Spring 4.2.5 + Hibernate + Tomcat 7 via Maven

The problem
I already followed these links below:
http://zeroturnaround.com/software/jrebel/quickstart/netbeans/
http://manuals.zeroturnaround.com/jrebel/standalone/maven.html

The situation:

My project uses tomcat maven plugin, so, I don’t need to have installed the tomcat server locally on my NetBeans IDE.

There is only one case the jRebel works fine, disabling tomcat maven plugin and install locally apache tomcat.

What else should I do ?

I need to use the jRebel with maven tomcat plugin.

Comment: Share with us your jrebel.lic, please!! My evaluation license time is over and I need to using this amazing plugin for Intellij Idea

Answer (score 1):

I you have already added jrebel plugin the only thing you may be missing MAVEN_OPTS setting.

```
set MAVEN_OPTS=-javaagent:/path/to/jrebel.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily run your embedded tomcat plugin by making two small changes:

1) Add Jrebel maven Plugin to your project so it takes care of generating the required "rebel.xml" file.

2) Add Jrebel to you JVM options using this line:

```
export JAVA_OPTIONS="-agentpath:{JRebel root folder}/lib/libjrebel64.so $JAVA_OPTIONS"
```

in Windows

```
export JAVA_OPTIONS="-agentpath:{JRebel root folder}/lib/libjrebel64.dylib $JAVA_OPTIONS"
```

(or you may want 32 bit of course)

and then run your tomcat as usual like `mvn tomcat7:run`

While tomcat is running. if you compile your code, new changes will be hot deployed and for static resources you don't need to do something.